# Sending custom headers required to load a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a webpage that requires an id and a token to be sent in the header for the page to load. A php login script returns the id and token. Then this id and token needs to be sent in the header of the page for it to load. Check is provided to look for these custom header, if not set, it is redirected to the login page. The page needs to be loaded from a javascript function. If I use window.location, it is redirected to the login page as the headers are not found. How do I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.example.com/apis/login.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(inputs),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.status == "success") {
            username = data.username;
            uid = data.uid;
            token = decodeURIComponent(data.token);
            loadpanel(username, uid, token);
        }
        else{
            alert(data.message);
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("could not connect to server");
    }
});

function loadpanel(username, uid, token) {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: "/haspanel.php",
        headers: {
            "U-Name" : username,
            "U-Id" : uid,
            "Auth-Token" : encodeURIComponent(token)
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location='/haspanel.php';
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("could not connect to server");
        }
    });
}
```

I know, this won't work, but I don't understand what is the workaround.

Comment: Please, show your attempts.

Comment: can you provide some code of how the headers are checked and how the page is redirected? depending on how it is checked, it can be set just as a cookie, which are automatically sent in the headers

Comment: Sure, I will update the post.. :)

Comment: maybe i'll extend it later if i have time, but i think you should stick to usual ways to do this, like authentification in cookies or PHP session variables. Your login.php should set them directly if credentials are valid. On return, you can just redirect to any PHP file, it will be able to retreive them without passing it again through JS

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this right? :

```
window.location = '/page.php?id='+ id +'&token='+ token +'';
```

Where `id` and `token` are variables that contain the required values of your id and variable parameters.

Comment: This is how I did it before, adding the uid and token as get parameters. However, this stores the uid and token in the browser history and is also available for copying on the url bar. So, I decided to put it in the header.